# Close All Popups with Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, dictionary, popup

I'm working on a map using Leaflet.js that uses a number of markers (eventually there will be ~40 markers). Each marker has a related popup with details. The default behaviour of Leaflet.js seems to be to automatically open at least one marker's popup (the last listed marker, I believe).

I'd like *all* the popups to be closed on the initial loading of the map page so users have to click the markers to open the popups. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186001/how-to-close-all-popups

Answer (score 78):

There is a clean method from your ***map*** object to close all open popups

```
map.closePopup();
```

Comment: This closes all popup for you or just one?

Comment: @JoSmo Just one in my case.

Comment: I would like to close all popups.
```map.closePopup();``` closes only the last one.

See: https://observablehq.com/d/6ce88f5b8e361005

Answer (score 18):

I managed to solve my problem by this piece of code:

```
$(".leaflet-popup-close-button")[0].click();
```

Hope it helps someone in future.

Comment: I think it's better to check whether the dom object exist first before executing the click(); in case there is no pop up at the time of execution.

Comment: This is really useful - I have my map set up to allow multiple popups open. When the amount open is greater than 3, I can use this to close the oldest open popup.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove your calls to `.openPopup()`.

Instead of

```
L.marker([57.70887, 11.97456]).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>Ideal Festival</b><br />2004").openPopup();
```

Use

```
L.marker([57.70887, 11.97456]).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>Ideal Festival</b><br />2004");
```

The click behavior will still be there (when users click on those markers, the popups will still appear), but the popups won't be visible when the page loads.

Answer (score 4):

```
  map.closePopup();
```

did not work for me as well and did not close the most recent popup.

So, I used the approach that was mentioned earlier with some modifications. Here is what worked for me.

Generalization of what  user2304819  suggested:

```
  var ButtonremoveNotidfications = L.easyButton({
                id: 'ButtonremoveNotidfications',
                states: [{
                    stateName: 'Show',
                    icon: '<strong>Clear notifications</strong>',
                    title: 'Show',
                    onClick: function (btn) { //Below is the closing module
                        var aa = $(".leaflet-popup-close-button").length
                        if (aa > 0) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < aa; i++) {
                                $(".leaflet-popup-close-button")[i].click();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
            ButtonremoveNotidfications.button.style.width = widthbuttonstyle;
            ButtonremoveNotidfications.button.style.height = heightbuttonstyle;
            ButtonremoveNotidfications.button.style.color = 'blue';
            ButtonremoveNotidfications.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".leaflet-popup-close-button").click()
```

try this after your map load completes.

Answer (score 0):

`popup.removeFrom(map)`

Is what worked for me.

Comment: That will not juts close it. It will totally remove it so that it cannot be opened again. That might be what is desired, bu tit might not

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't created layers for the popups, use:

```
 map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      layer.closePopup();
 });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@florian-boudot's https://stackoverflow.com/a/36940867/2095317 answer is right but there is a cache

If you see the documentation closely, `closePopup` method works only in 2 cases

1. It closes the last popup opened using `openPopup` method
2. If a popup object is passed as an argument, it closes only that popup

[image]

Here is an example

```js
// initiate your popup
let popup = L.popup()
          .setLatLng([lat,lang])
          .setContent("text")

// use the leaflet map object 
map.openPopup(popup);

// close the popup after 5s

// Case 1: closes popup as it was the last popup object opened with map object
setInterval(() => map.closePopup(), 5000);

// Case 2: If you want to be more accurate/specific which popup to close
// and have the popup object in a variable pass the popup object
setInterval(() => map.closePopup(popup), 5000);
```