# Closing angular-leaflet popups on event

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

Is there a function that I can call to close all open popups in the angular-leaflet directive? Working from the jQuery suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816173/close-all-popups-with-leaflet-js) I have tried the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.leaflet-popup-close-button').click();
```

but I get

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

alternatively, I have tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.leaflet-popup-close-button')[0].click();
```

but that does not work either:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the original Leaflet docs, the solution is to get the native Leaflet map object and call functions on that.

```
            leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
                map.closePopup();
            });
```